# summing values of variables in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get all the regular files opened by all the processes in the current session. I have this code

```
while read pid
do

        FILES_ACTUAL=$(lsof -p $pid | grep REG | wc -l)   


done < <(ps -o pid,tt -u $USER | grep $CURRENT_TERMINAL | awk '{print $1}')

echo $FILES_ACTUAL
```

but I don't know how to add up, inside the while,  the variable $FILES_ACTUAL..
I tried to use the awk command, but I couldn´t do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform bash arithmetic by enclosing the statements inside (()):

```
NEW_FILES=$(lsof -p $pid | grep REG | wc -l)
((FILES_ACTUAL+=NEW_FILES))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a comand called `expr` which does simple arithmetic operations with integers and can be used like this:

```
expr $VAR1 + $VAR2
```